# Access next,previous,play and pause of mediaplayer in android

Tags: android

In my android application,i want to apply OnPause,OnPlay,Next and previous,volume increase and decrease events on mediaplayer.
[image]
In the above image i just want to know how can i perform next,previous,play,pause events.
Could anyone please let me know where i can find these?

Please send me your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Accept some answers to previous questions, it'll give you reputation!

Comment: Is "mediaplayer" the `MediaPlayer` class, or something else?

Comment: I have edited my question to be more clear.Please check and let me know your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner in android (and my English isn't the best.. :( ), but i think you can do that with [android.media.MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) via its methods. For example, first you have to create a SurfaceView and your controll panel in the xml layout or in the code.In your Activity create a MediaPlayer instance and assign it with the SurfaceHolder of the view. Assign your controll "buttons" to the MediaPlayer's methods in the button's OnClickListener.